# Apache Hive command

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hive-query, hive-configuration

I have this question:  Show the top 5 game Disciplines for the countries who got more than 10 gold medals.

my code is:  select distinct t.discipline, m.team from teams t join medals m  on (t.noc=m.team and m.numbergold>10)  order by  m.team;

cloud you please help me with this code to show the top 5 game for each country?

change the code to display 5 games for each country

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the group by and windows function for your required result.
In 'numbergold' - Use windows functions like dense_rank so that you can filter on the top 5.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).